# 'fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in ..' error when setting up Git

Tags: wordpress, git, refspec

I'm trying to setup git with WPengine following the instructions here: (http://wpengine.com/git/#production) - but when I get down to the deploy step, I get the following error:

```
% git remote -v  
production  git@git.wpengine.com:production/workshop-wp.git (fetch)
production  git@git.wpengine.com:production/workshop-wp.git (push)
% git push production master ...
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in ...
```

Comment: You didn't actually use `...` in the push command, did you?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `...` in the push command. The correct syntax is

```
git push production master
```

I know that the instructions in the tutorial that you linked to say to do this:

```
git push production master ...
```

but that's just **blatantly incorrect**.

Comment: Thanks, that brings up this error: `% git push production master
FATAL: W any production/workshop-wp robertwilliams-robert_williams DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @user1406947 sorry, I don't know what your problem is at that point. Might be a repository access permissions issue, or you might be using the wrong URL for the repo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I was trying to deploy my GitHub repo name:

```
$ git remote add production git@git.wpengine.com:production/my_wordpress_app.git
```

Instead of deploying my wpengine username

```
$ git remote add production git@git.wpengine.com:production/robertwilliams.git
```